# Vlookup From Another Workbook Who's Name Changes On Daily Basis

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a way where it like :

```
=VLOOKUP(B7,'Y:\GIS\Reporting\2018\9Sep''18\Retention\Data Extract\Portal Data\[Retentions Portal Extract Day End_19Sep''18 Final.xlsm]Final Post Cleasing'!$I:$S,11,0)
```

I want this vlookup as code in vba to run day 19 than day 20 so i tried :

```
=VLOOKUP(B7,'Y:\GIS\Reporting\2018\9Sep''18\Retention\Data Extract\Portal Data\[Retentions Portal Extract Day End_TEXT(TODAY()-1,"ddmmm'yy") Final.xlsm]Final Post Cleasing'!$I:$S,11,0)
```

You see what I need to do is make the `vlookup` change the file name every day automatically the files names like:

- Retentions Portal Extract Day End_18Sep'18 Final
- Retentions Portal Extract Day End_19Sep'18 Final

Comment: Try `"Retentions Portal Extract Day End_" & Format(Now() - 1, "ddmmm'yy") & "Final.xlsm"`

Comment: @XLmatters sorry to answer late but it didn't work.

Comment: Make a cell (A2) in which you enter the daynumber and then make your formula: `VLOOKUP(B7,Indirect("....End_**"&A2&"Sep''...."))`

Comment: @Luuklag it just keep giving me #N/A
and i'm sure it is not  #N/A

Comment: How about you put the first and last part of that string in a cell as well, and then make Indirect(A1&A2&A3)

Comment: @Luuklag you mean like this `Extract Day End_"&Indirect(O5&P5&Q5)&'' Final.xlsm]`

Comment: No I mean split that entire filename into 3 parts, and join them with the indirect formula. So O5: 'Y:\....END_  then P5 your daynumber and Q5  Final.xlsm. Also be carefull with the space in the filename, that usually causes trouble.

Comment: You mean `=vlookup (B7, INDIRECT(O5&P5&Q5),11,0)`

Comment: Strange, the layout has to be pretty close to `Retentions Portal Extract Day End_" & Format(Now() - 1, "ddmmm'yy") & "Final.xlsm`  I've used this date  method in a vlookup formula in the past with success.

Comment: You mean `=vlookup (B7, INDIRECT(O5&P5&Q5),11,0)`.     While `O5=.... Extract Day End_` and `P5=23Sep'18` and `Q5= Final.xlsm] Final Post Cleasing'! $I:$S`

Comment: @XLmatters `=VLOOKUP(B7,'Y:\GIS\Reporting\2018\9Sep''18\Retention\Data Extract\Portal Data\[Retentions Portal Extract Day End_" & Format(Now() - 1, "ddmmm'yy") & "Final.xlsm]Final Post Cleasing'!$I:$S,11,0)` it says 
there is a problem with the formula and it marks `'Y:`